# Go - Copy bytes from uintptr to byte slice at offset

Tags: windows, go, winapi, sdk, slice

```
type MINIDUMP_IO_CALLBACK struct {
    Handle      uintptr //not relevant
    Offset      uint64  //The offset for the write operation from the start of the minidump data.
    Buffer      uintptr //A pointer to a buffer that contains the data to be written.
    BufferBytes uint32  //The size of the data buffer, in bytes
}

// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minidumpapiset/ns-minidumpapiset-minidump_io_callback

var dumpBuffer []byte //all bytes should be copied here

func copyDumpBytes(ioStruct *MINIDUMP_IO_CALLBACK) {
    size := unsafe.Sizeof(ioStruct.Buffer)
    dumpData := make([]byte, size)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(dumpData, uint64(ioStruct.Buffer)) // getting byte slice from pointer
    requiredSize := ioStruct.Offset + uint64(ioStruct.BufferBytes) // calculating required size to write it at the required offset
    if requiredSize > uint64(len(dumpBuffer)) {
        padding := make([]byte, requiredSize)
        dumpBuffer = append(dumpBuffer, padding...) // allocating new space in buffer, if existing is not enough
    }
    copy(dumpBuffer[ioStruct.Offset:], dumpData) //copying bytes itself into the buffer at the required offset
}
```

The **copyDumpBytes**() function is called by a **callback** function **multiple** **times** during the execution. It needs to store all the data it recieves into the **dumpBuffer** byte slice.

The byte slice is supposed to represent a **file**(windows process minidump file), but when stored into a file and opened with relevant program(WinDbg), it doesn't recognize the file structure.

```
ioutil.WriteFile("test.dmp", dumpBuffer, 0644)
```

My guess is that i messed up somewhere in this code, while copying the bytes.

Comment: Which IDE you are using?  The Link option of VC6.0 needs to change /pdbtype:sept to /pdbtype:con, otherwise the generated pdb file will not contain information such as custom structs, classes, etc.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal demo that builds the dump file which cannot be opened by WinDbg?

Comment: When you're doing `unsafe.Sizeof(ioStruct.Buffer)` you're getting the size of the `Buffer` member which is going to be 4 or 8 bytes. I think you want `ioStruct.BufferBytes` instead. Similary, you'd want to replace `binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64` with `copy`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an incomplete answer (as explained towards its end) but at this point I would say that the chief problem with your approach is

```golang
size := unsafe.Sizeof(ioStruct.Buffer)
dumpData := make([]byte, size)
```

With this code, you get the size of the [pointer-sized variable](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#uintptr) `ioStruct.Buffer`, which *is constant* on a given platform–32-bit on i386 and 64-bit on amd64 (64-bit Windows is an LLP64 platform).

Instead, that `Buffer` field of type `uintptr` is *a pointer* (an address of) a block of memory you should be copying, and the `BufferBytes` field contains the size of the data (in bytes) pointed at by the `Buffer` field.

So, in order to properly copy that data, you should produce a proper Go slice out of the raw memory pointer.

With Go ≥ 1.17, you can use [`unsafe.Slice`](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#Slice) for that¹:

```golang
func copyDumpBytes(iocb *MINIDUMP_IO_CALLBACK) {
    src := unsafe.Slice((*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(iocb.Buffer)), iocb.BufferBytes)

    dumpBuffer = append(dumpBuffer, src...)
}
```

Here:

1. The expression `unsafe.Pointer(iocb.Buffer)` produces a "proper" pointer which can participate in certain places of Go expressions operating on pointers (`uintptr` cannot–it's an integer type).
2. The result is then type-converted to `*byte` to produce a pointer to byte (actually–to a memory block of zero to any number of adjacent bytes).
3. Finally, a call to the [intrinsic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function) `unsafe.Slice` produces a proper Go slice, `[]byte`, whose backing array is the memory block pointed at by `Buffer`, and which contains `BufferBytes` elements (bytes).

You're then free to use the resulting slice in all the usual Go expressions and function calls, including `append()`.

⚠ Please note that while you've created a Go slice from the memory passed to us by the system, you do not own that memory, so you have to make sure no references (pointers) to that memory, our slice included, survive the handler's code, otherwise you'll get a classic "use-after-free" problem. `append()` copies the source's memory, so in my toy example this problem does not exist.

---

A problem which worries me, is that `Offset` member which is documented as

> The offset for the write operation from the start of the minidump data.

It *may* mean that there is no guarantee that the callback will be called "in a serial manner"–that is, with pieces of data sequentially following each other with no gaps in between. Instead, the wording of the manual page suggests the callback may be called with chunks of data to be written to *random* places of the resulting minidump file.

To understand what I mean, consider that the Win32 API function passing us the data of a resulting minidump has decided to break it in four chunks–like this:

```
|offset_1            |offset_2          |offset_3             |offset_4
+--------------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|          1         |        2         |          3          |          4          |
+--------------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
 <-    size_1      -> <-    size_2    -> <-      size_3     -> <-      size_4     ->
```

I'd say, the docs do not guarantee that you will receive these four callbacks in the same order as the chunks above are labeled; instead, the docs are formulated in a way that allow the callback to be called with the chunks in any order–say, like this:

1. `offset_4`, `size_4`;
2. `offset_2`, `size_2`;
3. `offset_1`, `size_1`;
4. `offset_3`, `size_3`.

If this is true, you cannot ignore `Offset` and rely on `append`-ing the data, and instead should somehow preallocate the resulting buffer and "patch it up" with the resulting data, or write the data directly to a file (each time positioning the file pointer using the seek operation before writing the next received chunk).

Anyway, this is a completely different question which has nothing to do with Go.

---

¹ With older versions of Go you usually employ a rather standard trick which does the same:

```golang
func copyDumpBytes(iocb *MINIDUMP_IO_CALLBACK) {
    src := (*[1<<31 - 1]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(iocb.Buffer))[:iocb.BufferBytes]

    dumpBuffer = append(dumpBuffer, src...)
}
```

Let's break it down:

1. As above, the expression `unsafe.Pointer(iocb.Buffer)` produces a "proper" Go pointer out of an `uintptr`-typed value.
2. The produced pointer is then type-converted to the type `*[1<<31 - 1]byte`, which is a pointer to (`*`) an array of bytes of size `1<<32 - 1` (that's the maximum size a Go array can have on a i386 architecture).
   The result of these two expressions is a pointer to an array of bytes. Its length is bogus ("infinite"), but that is dealt with by the last part of the expression.
3. The `[:iocb.BufferBytes]` is a slicing expression which produces a byte slice, `[]byte`, out of the source array of bytes, and makes the slice refer to the array's elements from that at index 0 through, and including, that at index `iocb.BufferSize-1`.